# sum of  fractional parts

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Any hints how to compute this sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\left[i\frac{K}{N}\right]^{p}?$$
where K  < N , $\left[\cdot\right]$  denotes fractional part,
$p\in N$

Comment: May I suggest that you not use $[x]$ for fractional part when everyone else uses it for integer part? Standard is $\lbrace x\rbrace$. 

Comment: I think the best hint is that the sum is independent of K when gcd(K,N) = 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article [On Certain Sums of Fractional Parts](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01238638) by Gandhi and Williams answers your question for $p=1$; it's likely that since 1974 this result has been generalized, but I wasn't able to find a reference.